# python ошибка пустой DataFrame - нет числовых данных для графика

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Z выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
z.shape
(9,)
type(z)
pandas.core.series.Series
z.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

Затем я получаю ошибку

```
Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

[drive.google.com/open?id=10JKlplhvsgI1qhLGAyVgQOxGC7ndt-EO](http://drive.google.com/open?id=10JKlplhvsgI1qhLGAyVgQOxGC7ndt-EO) 
Ссылка проекта на Colaboratory
[youtube.com/watch?v=_D1xhwXUebI&t=407s](http://Colaboratory%20youtube.com/watch?v=_D1xhwXUebI&t=407s) на 25 мин 10 сек видео, ноутбук из ссылки под видео, у автора все получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения Pandas вы пытаетесь нарисовать график столбца в котором находятся не числовые значения, а сложные объекты - в каждой ячейке находится список.

Для того, чтобы беспроблемно пользоваться методами Pandas убедитесь что в ячейках DataFrame/Series находятся скалярные значения, а не сложные/составные объекты.

---

**UPDATE:** причина многочисленных ошибок в том, что на момент создания видео по данной ссылке находился CSV файл с другими данными - сравните [вывод, показанный на 3 мин. 39 сек](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D1xhwXUebI&t=407s) с тем что выдаёт команда `df[:HEAD_ROWS_TO_SHOW]`:

```
In [17]: df = pd.read_csv(TITANIC_CSV_DATA_URL)

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    Unnamed: 0 Class     Sex    Age Survived  Freq
0            1   1st    Male  Child       No     0
1            2   2nd    Male  Child       No     0
2            3   3rd    Male  Child       No    35
3            4  Crew    Male  Child       No     0
4            5   1st  Female  Child       No     0
5            6   2nd  Female  Child       No     0
6            7   3rd  Female  Child       No    17
..         ...   ...     ...    ...      ...   ...
25          26   2nd    Male  Adult      Yes    14
26          27   3rd    Male  Adult      Yes    75
27          28  Crew    Male  Adult      Yes   192
28          29   1st  Female  Adult      Yes   140
29          30   2nd  Female  Adult      Yes    80
30          31   3rd  Female  Adult      Yes    76
31          32  Crew  Female  Adult      Yes    20

[32 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10JKlplhvsgI1qhLGAyVgQOxGC7ndt-EO

Comment: Ссылка проекта на Colaboratory, откуда там взялись объекты не пойму

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D1xhwXUebI&t=407s на 25 мин 10 сек видео, ноутбук из ссылки под видео, у автора все получается , у меня появляются объекты

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10JKlplhvsgI1qhLGAyVgQOxGC7ndt-EO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @svil, если не понимаете, то попробуйте задать новый SO вопрос и привести в нем __воспроизводимый__ пример данных

Comment: Вопрос будет такой же

Comment: Основная ценность данного ресурса - это база знаний, на которую попадают из поисковиков. Вы задали вопрос почему Pandas не рисует график - я ответил на заданный вопрос. Люди, у которых будет такое же сообщение об ошибке попадут на эту страницу и смогут понять почему Pandas не рисует график...

Comment: @svil Пожалуйста, поясните, что вам не понятно в предложенном ответе?

Comment: Все понятно, пока ищу ответ самостоятельно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Извините за тупость.